# How to combine elements from one array with each element from another array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to combine elements from one array with every element from another array, I tried looking for some solutions but I couldn't figure it out.

Take these two arrays for example:

```
num = [1,2,3]

let = ["a","b","c"]
```

I want to combine them in order to obtain:

```
combined = [[1, "a"], [1, "b"], [1, "c"], [2, "a"], [2, "b"], [2, "c"], 
            [3, "a"], [3, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
num = [1,2,3]
let = ["a","b","c"]

num.product let
#=>[[1, "a"], [1, "b"], [1, "c"], [2, "a"], [2, "b"], [2, "c"], [3, "a"], [3, "b"], [3, "c"]]
```